# How can use more than function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question is I have three select boxes and user select first select box's option than select second select box's option and finally the third select box's options will load by user selection. It works but when user select the third select box's option I want to display a text but It doesn't work here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var zero="0,00";
    var one="0,01";
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#main').on('change', '.select-box', function() {

            if ($(".select-box option[value='1']").prop('selected') && $(".select-box option[value='1986']").prop('selected')) {

                $('#street').html("<option value='2'>test</option><option value='3'>test2</option>");

            }
       if ($(".select-box option[value='1']").prop('selected') && $(".select-box option[value='1986']").prop('selected') && $(".select-box option[value='3']").prop('selected')) {
           document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML=""+zero;
      }

        });

    });
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var x="",i;
    for(i=1986;i<2013;i++)
    {
    x=x + "<option value='"+i+"'> " + i + "</option>";
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML="<select class='select-box'><option>Empty/option>"+x+"</select>";
    });
    </script>





    </head>
    <body>  
        <p id="forloop"></p>
        <div id="main">

    <select class="select-box">

          <option value="1">Hello</option>

        </select> 
       <p></p>
      <select class="select-box" id="street">
      <option>Empty<option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <p id="demo3">

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do. Do you have any error? What does *doesn't work* mean? Can you provide a full test case?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple HTML syntax errors in your string concatenation. You're already using jQuery; for sanity's sake (yours and ours) stop constructing HTML with strings.

```
var selectBox = $('<select>');

$('<option>')
    .text('Empty')
    .appendTo(selectBox);

for (var i = 1986; i < 2013; i++) {
    $('<option>')
        .text(i)
        .val(i)
        .appendTo(selectBox);
}

selectBox.appendTo($('#forloop'));
```

Comment: And, what does this have to do with the OP's problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 he has multiple HTML syntax errors in his string concatenations.

Comment: @jbabey - then you should explain what the problem was and why your code fixes it.  To the regular reader, it just looks like you want him to write his code a different way and aren't actually addressing the problem.

Comment: The problem is when u click "test2", the text "0" will display

Comment: @jfriend00 i have edited to clarify how this change will help fix the problem. thanks for the input.